# Subset panel data by group

Tags: r, panel, subset

I would like to subset an unbalanced panel data set by group. For each group, I would like to keep the two observations in the first and the last years.

How do I best do this in R? For example:

```
dt <- data.frame(name= rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(3,2,3)), 
                 year=c(2001:2003,2000,2002,2000:2001,2003))

> dt
  name year
1    A 2001
2    A 2002
3    A 2003
4    B 2000
5    B 2002
6    C 2000
7    C 2001
8    C 2003
```

What I would like to have:

```
  name year
1    A 2001
3    A 2003
4    B 2000
5    B 2002
6    C 2000
8    C 2003
```

Answer (score 2):

[dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) should help. check out first() & last() to get the values you are looking for and then filter based on those values.

```
dt <- data.frame(name= rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(3,2,3)), year=c(2001:2003,2000,2002,2000:2001,2003))

library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(first = first(year)
        ,last = last(year)) %>%
  filter(year == first | year == last) %>%
  select(name, year)

  name year
1    A 2001
2    A 2003
3    B 2000
4    B 2002
5    C 2000
6    C 2003
```

*your example to didn't mention any specific order but it that case, arrange() will help

Comment: Thanks. But it seems dplyr is not available anymore.

Comment: @Gary: ???  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html Much more likely that you have an old version of R that's not seeing this package ...

Comment: @BenBolker my guess is that OP doesn't know he can install external packages, e.g. using `install.packages("dplyr")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .SD[c(1L, .N)], by = name]
#    name year
# 1:    A 2001
# 2:    A 2003
# 3:    B 2000
# 4:    B 2002
# 5:    C 2000
# 6:    C 2003
```

Or if you only have two columns

```
dt[, year[c(1L, .N)], by = name]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple using `by` to split the data.frame by group and then return the head and tail of each group.

```
> do.call(rbind, by(dt, dt$name, function(x) rbind(head(x,1),tail(x,1))))
    name year
A.1    A 2001
A.3    A 2003
B.4    B 2000
B.5    B 2002
C.6    C 2000
C.8    C 2003
```

`head` and `tail` are convenient, but slow, so a slightly different alternative would probably be faster on a large data.frame:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dt, dt$name, function(x) x[c(1,nrow(x)),]))
```

Comment: `dt[as.logical(ave(dt$year,dt$name,FUN=function(x) seq_along(x) %in% c(1,length(x)))),]` as an alternative using `ave`